# Need help with proof about Diophantine equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, proof-explanation, pythagorean-triples

The way I am planning to arrange this is by providing fragments of the proof, so I can understand what's going on before forging ahead, so if you are going to help me, keep in mind that I am going to be updating the thread with the missing fragments. I appreciate so much your help!.

> Theorem 7-1. A general primitive solution of $x^2+y^2=z^2$, $y$ even, $x>0,y>0,z>0$,
>
> is given by
>   $$x=a^2-b^2,y=2ab,z=a^2+b^2$$
>
> where $a$ and $b$ are prime to each other and not both odd, and $a>b>0$.

The above theorem and the proof below are from [LeVeque's Elementary Theory of Numbers](https://books.google.com/books?id=BYvMAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA108).

Proof: It is easily verified that for every such pair of integers a and b, the corresponding integers $x,y,z$ satisfy all the requirements. It remains to show that every solution arises from suitably chosen a and b satisfying the conditions of the theorem. (It's not clear to me what we are trying to prove and besides that, how do you verify for every such pair of integers a and b, the corresponding integers $x,y,z$ satisfy all the requirements).

Suppose that $x^2+y^2=z^2$. Since $(x,y,z)=1$, we also have $(y,z)=1$, so that $(z-y,z+y)=1$ or $2$. But z is odd and y is even and therefore $(z-y,z+y)=1$. (why is $(y,z)=1$?) I need a deeper explanation of the latter).

$$x^2=(z-y)(z+y)$$

We deduce that $z-y$ and $z+y$ must be odd squares (How?, an odd square is a number in the form $x^2$ that is odd right?), since they are positive. Now if $t$ and $u$ are integers of the same parity (both even or both odd), there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $t=a+b$ and $u=a-b$ (why are we doing this?), namely $a=(t+u)/2$ and $b=(t-u)/2$ (ok here we just solve for b and a). Applying this in the case where $t$ and $u$ are the odd numbers of which $z+y$ and $z-y$ are the squares, respectively, we can set

$$z-y=(a-b)^2\\
z+y=(a+b)^2$$

(How is the latter true?)

Comment: $x^2 = z^2 - y^2$ so if $gcd(y,z) = a \ne 1$ then the RHS is divisble by $a^2$ so the LHS is divisble by $a^2$ and $gcd(x,y,z) = a$

Comment: ok what about this $(z-y,z+y)=1$

Comment: come on... $   {}$

Comment: why is it 1 or 2?, sorry, it's hard for me to see it.

Comment: same trick, if $b$ divides $z+y$ and $z-y$ then ..

Comment: $(z+y)+(z-y)= ?$

Comment: $b|2z$ what does that tell about the gcd?

Comment: :) and you know that in general $gcd(a,b) = gcd(a+b,b)$ $ {}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I am going to post the other parts of the proof.

Comment: I am going to set a bounty for this question. I really need help on it.

Comment: It turns out I can't

Comment: It seems that several of your questions are of the form that you have proof from some text and you want to explain some steps in that proof. The tag ([tag:proof-explanation]) is for the questions of this kind, see [the tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-explanation/info).

Answer (score 1):

First of, this fact is useful. (And I will use it below.)

> **Fact 1.** For integers such that $x^2+y^2=z^2$ the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> - $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$
> - $\gcd(x,y)=1$
> - $\gcd(x,z)=1$
> - $\gcd(y,z)=1$
>
> In other words, if two numbers in a Pythagorean triple are coprime, then it is a primitive Pythagorean triple.

I leave for you to think a bit about this. (Just think about what happens if some $d\mid x$ and $d\mid y$ for some $d>1$. Other cases are similar.)

---

Another useful fact:

> **Fact 2.** If $m$ and $n$ are integers such that $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then $\gcd(m+n,m-n)$ is either $1$ or $2$.

See [Prove $\gcd(a+b, a-b) = 1$ or $\gcd(a+b, a-b) = 2$ if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32737/prove-gcdab-a-b-1-or-gcdab-a-b-2-if-gcda-b-1)

---

> It's not clear to me what we are trying to prove and besides that, how do you verify for every such pair of integers a and b, the corresponding integers $x,y,z$ satisfy all the requirements.

Suppose $a>b>0$ are coprime and they have different parity. Then for $x=a^2-b^2$, $y=2ab$, $z=a^2+b^2$ we have.

- $x^2+y^2=z^2$, which can be verified simply by plugging in and algebraic manipulation: $$(a^2-b^2)^2+(2ab)^2=a^4-2a^2b^2+b^4+4a^2b^2 = a^4+2a^2b^2+b^4=(a^2+b^2)^2$$
- $y$ is clearly even and it is also clear that $x,y,z>0$;
- $\gcd(x,z)=\gcd(a^2-b^2,a^2+b^2)$ can be only $1$ or $2$. But since $a$ and $b$ have different parity, neither of the numbers $x$ and $z$ is even. To we have $\gcd(x,z)=1$.

In summary: The above shows that the numbers $x$, $y$, $z$ indeed form a primitive Pythagorean triple.

> Why is $(y,z)=1$?

See Fact 1 above.

> ...and therefore $(z-y,z+y)=1$. I need a deeper explanation of the latter

By Fact 2 we know that $\gcd(z-y,z+y)$ is either $1$ or $2$. But since both $z-y$ and $z+y$ are odd, it cannot be $2$. So the remaining possibility is $\gcd(z-y,z+y)=1$.

> We deduce that $z-y$ and $z+y$ must be odd squares. (How?, an odd square is a number...)

If $x^2$ is a square and it is product of two coprime numbers, then each of them must be square, see: [If a and b are relatively prime and ab is a square, then a and b are squares.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284636/if-a-and-b-are-relatively-prime-and-ab-is-a-square-then-a-and-b-are-squares)

Similarly, each of the factors must be odd, if you want get an odd number.

> ... $z-y=(a-b)^2$, $z+y=(a+b)^2$. How is the latter true?

We know that $z+y=t^2$ and $z-y=s^2$ for some integers $s$ and $t$. We also know that $s$ and $t$ are both even. So there exists $a$, $b$ such that $a+b=t$ and $a-b=s$, meaning that
\begin{align*}
z+y&=(a+b)^2\\
z-y&=(a-b)^2
\end{align*}