# Two integers whose product is square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, square-numbers

I am trying to prove the following statement.

Let $d = \gcd(x_1,x_2)$. If $x_1 x_2$ is a square, then ($x_1 = d M^{2}$ and $x_2 = dN^2$) or ($x_1 = -d M^{2}$ and $x_2 = -dN^2$), where $\gcd(N,M) =1$.

This is true if $d=1$: [If a and b are relatively prime and ab is a square, then a and b are squares.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/284636)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: Suppose a prime $p\mid x_1x_2$, but $p\nmid d$.  Then, what do you know?

Comment: I do not really understand what is meant by this hint ...

Comment: This might help you a bit: [If a and b are relatively prime and ab is a square, then a and b are squares.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/284636)

Comment: Where does the problem come from? Including the source could count towards [adding some context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) to the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note $\,x_1 x_2 = c^2\,\Rightarrow\, x_1/x_2 = (c/x_2)^2 = (a/b)^2\,$ for $\,a/b\,$ in least terms, i.e. $(a,b) = 1$.

[By Euclid](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/166839/242) $\begin{align} (a,\ b)\ &=1\\ \iff\! (a^2,b^2)&=1\end{align}\,\ $ so $\,\ \dfrac{x_1}{x_2} = \dfrac{a^2}{b^2}\,\Rightarrow\begin{align}x_1 = d a^2\\ x_2 = d b^2\end{align},\ d\in\Bbb Z\ $ by [Unique Fractionization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825871/242)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an informal sketch:  Consider a prime $p$ which divides $x_1x_2$.  Because $x_1x_2$ is a square, the maximum power of $p$ dividing $x_1x_2$ is even, call it $2k$.  The maximum power of $p$ dividing $d$ is some number $m$, which is the maximum power dividing one of $x_1,x_2$.  Say it is $x_1$.  Then the maximum power of $p$ divding $x_2$ is $2k-m$, $p$ does not divide $M$ and the power of $p$ dividing $\frac {x_2}d$ is $2k-2m$, which is even.  This justifies that $\frac {x_2}{d}$ is a square.

Answer (score 0):

Define $y_i = x_i /d.\,$ Then $\,x_2x_2 = k^2\,\Rightarrow\,y_1 y_2 = (k/d)^2\,$ and $\,k/d\in\Bbb Z\,$ by the Rational Test. Since $y_1,y_2$ are *coprime* factors of a square [it follows](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21637/242) that both are squares (up to sign). $ $  **QED**

Comment: i.e. cancelling the common factor $d$ reduces to the well-known coprime case (which is asked an answered *many* times here).

Comment: and $1=$ gcd$(y_1,y_2) =$ gcd$(M^2,N^2) =$ $\left( \text{gcd}(M,N) \right)^2$, so $\text{gcd}(M,N)  = 1$.

Comment: @Tithus248 Yes, since $y_1,y_2$ are coprime, so too are their factors $\,M,N\ \ \ $

Answer (score -1):

As $\gcd(x_{1}, x_{2}) = d$, there exists an $n, m$, such that:

$x_{1} = \pm \;d\cdot m$ with $m \geq 1$

and

$x_{2} = \pm \;d\cdot n$, with $n\geq 1$.

Their sign should be the same as a square is positive.

Now as $d^{2} \vdash x_{1}x_{2}$, $nm = \frac{x_{1}x_{2}}{d^{2}}$ should be also square.

Also as $\gcd(x_{1}, x_{2}) = d$, $\gcd(\frac{x_{1}}{d}, \frac{x_{2}}{d})=1$, that is $\gcd(n, m) = 1$, $n$ and $m$ should be also square.

This means there exists an $N\geq 1$ and an $M\geq 1$, such that:
$n = N^{2}$ and $m = M^{2}$.

### Note

To prove that:

> if two numbers $a, b$, with $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ have a square product each of them should be a square

you can say that:

> if there exists a prime number such that $p^{2k} \vdash ab$, then either $p^{2k} \vdash a $ or $p^{2k} \vdash b$, because otherwise $\gcd(a, b) \neq 1$

Comment: The conclusion in the line  "now as..." is unjustified.

Comment: See the note. $d^{2}$ and $nm$ are two numbers with gcd 1, that have a square product.

Comment: But $\ \gcd(d^2,nm) = 1\ $ is not generally true. Also the proof of the Note is not correct.

Comment: $gcd(d^{2}, nm)=1$ is based on the fact that $gcd(d, n)=1$ and $gcd(d, m)=1$.

Also why is the proof not correct? It is a proof by contradiction.

Comment: But that's not true, e.g. consider $\, 8(18) = 12^2\,$ where $\,m,n,d = 4,9,2\,$ and $\,(m,d) = (4,2) = 2 \neq 1.\ $  As for the Note, the argument not derive the claimed result.

Comment: But $gcd(m, d) = 2$ in this case

Comment: Thus $\,(d^2,nm)\neq 1$ so your claim is false.

Comment: No if $(d, m) = 1$ and $(d, n) = 1$  then $(d^{2}, nm)=1$, that's my argument.

Comment: But $\,(d,m) = 2,\,$ not $1\ \ $

Comment: That's your example not mine. That's why it is not a contradiction to my argument. Also the note holds because it indicates that the two $a, b$ have distinct square prime factors and as so they are square.
A counterexample would be:
Find me three numbers $(n, m, d)$ such that if $(d, m) = 1$ and $(d, n) = 1$, then $(d^{2}, nm) \neq 1$

Comment: But your argument fails on that example, which is a particular case of the OP's problem. There are infinitely many more counterexamples like that to your argument.  I can't make any sense of your argument in the note. It seems you have problems understanding logical deduction.

Comment: So the problem with my argument was that I assumed that (d, m) = 1, in the second line. 
Now I removed that part from the proof and I think it still works. Also please don't be insulting,

Comment: There are still errors, e.g.. $\,x_1 x_2/ d^2 \,$ is the square of a *rational* but your note only works for squares of *integers* (so it seems, it is not clear what is intended there). We can complete the proof in various ways, e.g. see my answers here.

Comment: If $d^{2} \vdash x_{1}x_{2}$ then $\frac{x_{1}x_{2}}{d^{2}}$ is not rational. It is an integer and it should be square, as dividing a square by a square that divides it should give you again a square. Also this is not related with my note. My note has to do with $(n, m) = 1$.

Comment: Again it is not clear what you intend. You have $\,(x_1/d)(x_2/d)  d^2 = c^2.\ $ How do you proceed from that?

Comment: As for the Note, perhaps you intend an inductive proof e.g. [as here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1104334/242), using FTA = unique prime factoization, but so little is said I can't be sure.

Comment: Yes it has to do with FTA. Also can you have $d^{2} \vdash c^{2}$ and $d \not \vdash c$? If no then $\frac{c}{d}$ is an integer and $nm = (\frac{c}{d})^{2}$ is a square. My argument is really simple: prove that n*m is a square and then prove that n, m are both squares.

Comment: Yes, $\,d^2\mid c^2\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid c,\,$ which I proved by the Rational Root Test in [one of](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3381119/242) my answers (it can also be proved by Euclid's Lemma, unique factorizaton, etc). It is an important step where errors are often made, so it  should be *explicitly* mentioned and cited / proved if it is used. With the changes you propose it seems that what you now intend is equivalent to what I wrote in the linked answer (which is  different from what you first wrote). But there stil are gaps (and doubts) on what is written in the answer